# How to align brackets with the code they contain?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is it possible to use clang-format to achieve the following style?

```
int foo(int bar)
   {
   if(bar == 1)
      {
      cout << bar;
      return bar;
      }
   else
      return bar - 1;
   }
```

I have gone through all the clang-format style options shown [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and it seems like it's not possible.

I am also having trouble indenting all brackets. The IndentBraces option in BraceWrapping allows me to do so for things like if statements and loops, but it does not work for things like function definitions, class definitions, and namespace definitions.

If it's not possible, do you have a suggestion for a tool and/or text editor available on linux that would allow me to do so?

Comment: I don't think `clang-format` supports that style.  (It's called Whitesmiths style.)

Comment: Okay, thanks Elijay. I think I can figure it out now that I know the name for it.

Comment: What a peculiar style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html), which provides Whitesmith formatting with the "style=whitesmith" option.